# Subobject classifier of a slice category

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

Fix a set $I$ and consider the category $\mathbf C$ where the objects are the maps  $x:X\to I$ in $\mathbf {Set}$, and the morphisms are the maps $f:X\to Y$ such that  $x=yf$. What is a subobject classifier for $\mathbf C$? The only way thing that came to my mind was to  define the special
object as $\pi_1:I\times  I\to I$ (the projection on the first copy of $I$), and to  choose $\langle 1_I,1_I\rangle$ as the map from the terminal object. Given a  monomorphism $h:S\rightarrowtail X$ (s.t. $s=hx$), if I chose as "characteristic function" $\langle x,x \rangle :X\to  I\times I $, the diagram obtained is commutative  but I don't know if it's a pullback;  honestly it  doesn't seem a subobject classifier in any way to me. Can you  just give me a hint to find the special object, to start? Thank you

P.S. I don't know how much standard it is, but the notation $\langle a,b\rangle :  C\to A\times B$, given arrows $a:C\to A$, $b:C\to B$, is the map defined using the universal property of the product.

Comment: Why not construct it from the subobject classifier in $\mathbf{Set}$? Or another way to think of it: what do subobjects of $1_I:I\to I$ look like in $\mathbf{Set}/I$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1: There is an equivalence of categories $\mathbf{Set}/I \simeq \mathbf{Set}^I$.

Hint 2: The subobject classifier in a product of categories with subobject classifiers is easy to describe.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand; I think that using $\mathbf{Hom}(I,-)\cong \prod_I (-)$, since in the product category things are done componentwise, I should use as a special object $\prod _I \{0,1\}$. However I don't see why the $\mathbf {Set\setminus I} $ is equivalent to $\mathbf{Hom}(I,-)$ and not to $\mathbf{Hom}(-,I)$

Comment: I don't write $\mathbf{Set} \setminus I$ and I don't write $\mathrm{Hom}(I,-)$. Recall the definitions of a) slice categories, b) product categories. Then you need to check that a map $X \to I$ is "essentially" the same as an $I$-indexed family of sets.